# Training a Siamese Network with Caffe

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am training a simple siamese network that compares a pair of images.  I followed the example given with the [caffe(siamese)](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/siamese) and made my own model.

My issue is with the Constrastive Loss function. The detail of this function implementation is caffe is defined [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1ContrastiveLossLayer.html). In my implementation I used a margin = 1, defined as follows

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "ContrastiveLoss"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "data_p"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  contrastive_loss_param {
    margin: 1
  }
}
```

My data are labeled as ***0*** if dissimliar and ***1*** if similar. I am confused about the margin of contrastive loss function. How is the margin parameter selected?

[Page 3 of the initial paper by Hadsell et.al](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf) states margin > 0 but is there any upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's like a hyper-parameter.
A large margin would separate dissimilar data with a large margin but make it difficult to train the network. A small margin would learn a bad network easily. In general, you are supposed to choose different margins for different dataset. For the upper bound, it's determined by the bottom 'data' and 'data_p'. If value range of 'data' and 'data_p' is constrained, such as its absolute value is less than 1, then there is an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Margin in Siamese network is considered as `hyper parameter`. A large value of margin will make the convergence extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of the margin is the maximum distance between samples the loss formulation can get. So it depends on the distance chosen: If its cosine distance, it's 1, if its euclidian distance, it's unbounded.
Thie blogpost explaining ranking losses computation explains it [https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss](https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss/)/